# Iterate several Objects with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I got the following JSON data structure that I would like to output in Handlebars template

```
"data": [
    {
        "content_1": "some content",
        "array_1": ["value_1","value_2"],
        "array_2": ["value_A","value_B"]
    }
]
```

With the following Handlebars approach I can iterate all value in array_1

```
{{#each array_1}}
<div>{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

resulting in

```
<div>value_1</div>
<div>value_2</div>
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
<div>value_1</div>
<div>value_A</div>
<div>value_2</div>
<div>value_B</div>
```

I try several combination of each without any success. What could be the options to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an helper for this. Otherwise you can still merge the array.